# how to enable/disable div using javascript in timer

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I have three div's on my page. I want to show the div's one by one using timer in javascript. that means, when the first div is on, the other 2 should be off and henceforth...

Please reply with some codes in javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say you have these elements:

```
<div id="el1">element 1</div>
<div id="el2">element 2</div>
<div id="el3">element 3</div>
```

start by not displaying them:

```
<style>
#el1,#el2,#el3{display:none;}
</style>
```

then show them one by one:

```
<script>
(function(){
  var i=1;
  function show(){
    for(var j=1;j<4;++j)document.getElementById('el'+j).style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('el'+i).style.display='block';
    if(3==i++)return;
    setTimeout(show, 2000);
  }
  show();
})();
</script>
```

(the above is not tested)

Comment: i tried this code but for some reason its not working, it just displays 1st div and does not continue further, can you tell me what could be the reason for the same...

It will be highly appreciated..
Thanks for the help..