# Disable a div element for the next x seconds

Tags: jquery

I have a div element that works as refresh button using jQuery. What I want to do is stop user pressing it all the time. Let's say I want to disable it for the next 15 seconds. How can I do that?

**HTML PART**

```
<div class="am_outter_div">    
<div class="header">ΜΕΝΟΥ</div>
<div class="button_1">BACK</div>
<div class="button_2" id="am_refresh_button">REFRESH</div>
<div class="button_3">TOP</div>
<div class="button_4">NEXT</div>
</div><br><br>

<div id="av_refresh_div">Blah blah blah...</div>
```

**JQUERY PART**

```
var $JQ_ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $JQ_(document).ready(function(){
    $JQ_("#am_refresh_button").click(function(){
    $JQ_("#av_refresh_div").load("index.php #av_refresh_div").fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);});
    });
```

Also **JSFIDDLE** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GreenMadness/ZdFkf/)...

Comment: this is similar question asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110936/how-to-enable-disable-div-using-javascript-in-timer

Comment: How about using timers ?

Comment: @MadanRam: Hmmm no I don't think so...

Comment: @Triode: Of course, no problem. Any example? I am really new in jQuery!!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this:

```
var $JQ_ = jQuery.noConflict(), 
    $btbnRefresh = $JQ_("#am_refresh_button");

 function refreshBind(){     

     $btbnRefresh.on("click",function(){

    // after once click unbind click handler
    $JQ_(this).off("click");

    //show div fade
    $JQ_("#av_refresh_div").load("index.php #av_refresh_div").fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000); 

        // after some time re-bind again onclick
        setTimeout(function(){
            $btbnRefresh.on("click",refreshBind);
        },10000);

    });     
}

refreshBind();
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdFkf/5/

i hope it helps.

Comment: It works but one detail... When user clicks on it, after ten seconds has to do double click to work!!! Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

you could do the following:

1. disabling your div when it's clicked
2. setting a timeout, which will reactivate your div after x seconds

try this:

```
$("#am_refresh_button").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("disabled") != "disabled")
    {
        $("#av_refresh_div").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#av_refresh_div").load("index.php #av_refresh_div").fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#av_refresh_div").removeAttr("disabled");
    }, 10000); // <-- your time (10 sec atm)
});
```

Comment: I am trying it but something is wrong... Can you please make a jsfiddle example?

Comment: here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/tUGvS/1/ btw. I just updated my answer (I had forgotten to check whether or not the disabled attr. is set when your refresh button was clicked)

Answer (score 0):

You could unbind the click event and then set a timeout to rebind it after 15 seconds. Alternatively set a variable on the element to indicate if it's enabled or not:

```
var $JQ_ = jQuery.noConflict();
$JQ_("#av_refresh_div").data("isEnabled", true);

$JQ_(document).ready(function(){
    $JQ_("#am_refresh_button").click(function(){
        if ($JQ_("#av_refresh_div").data("isEnabled")) { 
            $JQ_("#av_refresh_div").data("isEnabled", false);             
            $JQ_("#av_refresh_div").load("index.php#av_refresh_div").fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $JQ_("#av_refresh_div").data("isEnabled", true); 
            }, 15000);
        }
    });
});
```

However you might be better off using actual HTML `button`s, then you could do the same but actual disable/enable them (so they'd appear greyed out) which would give feedback to the user that something is happening. Also they'd be obviously clickable (but I guess your divs will be too once they're styled, in which case you might want to add/remove a class to indicate clickability is some visible way).

Answer (score 0):

```
$JQ_("#am_refresh_button").click(function(){
    //Disable logic goes here
    setTimeOut(function(){
        //Enable the dive here
    },yourDelay);
});
```

You can add any number of time you want. Time is normally provided in milliseconds.

Or

```
var divEnabled = true;
$JQ_("#am_refresh_button").click(function(){
    if(!divEnabled)
       return;
    divEnabled = false;
    setTimeOut(function(){
        divEnabled = true;
    },yourDelay);
});
```

Comment: I think you want `setTimeout` there, otherwise it's going to keep firing (and maybe re-enabling the DIV early after several click events).

Comment: Appreciating your note on that, changed